# What is the namespace for ShimsBehaviors in Microsoft Shims?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

The [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_Changing_the_default_behavior) describes using the `ShimsBehaviors` class to modify the default behavior of shims. In what namespace is this class located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the class in the documentation is misspelled. It should be `ShimBehaviors` (note "Shim" not "Shims").

The namespace is: Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims